# Understanding proof of the Theorem 11.7 (Bonnet's Theorem) ( John Lee's Riemannian manifolds )

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

I'm reading the John Lee's book 'Riemannian Manifolds-An Introduction to Curvature', proof of the Theorem 11.7. and stuck at some statements. The theorem states as follows :

> Theorem 11.7. ( Bonnet's Theorem ) Let $M$ be a complete, connected, Riemannian manifold all of whose sectional curvatures are bounded below by a positive constant $1/R^2$. Then $M$ is compact, with a finite fundamental group, and with diameter less than or equal to $\pi R$.

*Proof.* The first step is to show that the diameter of $M$ is no greater than $\pi R$. Suppose the contrary : then there are points $p,q \in M$, and (by the Hopf-Rinow theorem : his book Cor.6.15) a minimizing unit speed geodesic segment $\gamma$ from $p$ to $q$ of length $L > \pi R$. Since $\gamma$ is minimizing, its index form is nonnegative (his book Cor. 10.13), We will derive a contradiction by constructing a proper (c.f. his book p.98) normal vector field $V$ along $\gamma$ such taht $I(V,V) <0$. By direct computation,

**Let $E$ be any parallel normal unit vector field along $\gamma$**, and let
$$ V(t) := ( \sin\frac{\pi t}{L})E(t).$$

**Q.1.** **My first question is**, why can we choose parallel normal unit vector field $E$ along $\gamma$? Here, 'parallel' means $D_t E =0$ ( the covariant derivative along $\gamma$ ). We have a theorem (his book Theorem 4.11) : Given a curve $\gamma : I \to M$, $t_0 \in I$, and a vector $V_0 \in T_{\gamma(t_0)}M$, there exists a unique parallel vector field $V$ along $\gamma$ such that $V(t_0) = V_0$.

And the 'normal' means $E(t) \perp \dot{\gamma}(t)$ for all $t$. Anyway, can we construct parallel normal unit vector field along $\gamma$? How?

And, he continue to argue as follows :

Observe that $V$ vanishes at $t=0$ and $t=L$, so $V$ is a proper normal vector field along $\gamma$. ( Note the similarity between $V$ and the formulas $(10.5)$, $(10.6)$ for Jacobi fields on the sphere of radius $L/\pi$ ). By direct computation,

$$ D_tV(t) = \frac{\pi}{L}(\cos \frac{\pi t}{L})E(t)$$
$$ D_t^2V(t) = -\frac{\pi^2}{L^2}(\sin \frac{\pi t}{L})E(t),$$

and so

$$ I(V,V) = - \int_{0}^{L} \langle D_t^2V + R(V,\dot{\gamma})\dot{\gamma},V \rangle  dt$$

..( Omitted )

**Q.2.** I don't know why this final equality is true. It seems that he used next theorem ( his book, Proposition 10.14 )

> Proposition 10.14. For any pair of proper normal vector fields $V,W$ along a geodesic segment $\gamma$,
> $ I(V,W) = -\int_{a}^{b} \langle D_t^2 V + R(V,\dot{\gamma})\dot{\gamma},W \rangle dt -\Sigma_{i=1}^{k}\langle \Delta_iD_t V , W (a_i) \rangle $, where $\{ a_i \}$ are the points where $V$ is not smooth, and $\Delta_{i}D_t V$ is the jump in $D_tV$ at $t=a_i$.

**My question is**, in our case, why $\Sigma_{i=1}^{k}\langle \Delta_iD_t V , V (a_i) \rangle = 0$ ? What the term 'jump' exactly means?

**Now, accept next statement** : Let $M$ be a complete, connected Riemannian manifold all of whose sectional curvatures are bounded below by a positive constant $1/ R^2$, then the diameter $\operatorname{diam}(M):= \sup \{ d(p,q) : p, q \in M\} \le \pi R$.

In the third paragraph in the proof, he argues as follows :

To show that $M$ is compact, we just choose a base point $p$ and note that every point in $M$ can be connected ( by the Hopg-Rinow theorem ) to $p$ by a geodesic segment of length at most $\pi R$. Therefore, $\exp_p : \bar{B}_{\pi R}(0) \to M $ is surjective, so $M$ is the continuous image of a compact set.

**Q.3.** I don't understand why the $\exp_p : \bar{B}_{\pi R}(0) \to M $ is surjective, although it seems possible. Let $\mathcal{E} := \{ V \in TM := \uplus_{p\in M}T_p M : \gamma_V  \operatorname{is defined on an interval containing} [0,1] \}$, where $\gamma_V$ is the maximal geodesic. Note that since $M$  is complete, each $\gamma_V$ is defined for all $t\in \mathbb{R}$.
Then the exponential map $\exp$ is defined by $\exp(V) := \gamma_V(1)$. And for each $p \in M$, the restricted exponential map $\exp_p$ is the restriction of $\exp$ to the set $\mathcal{E}_p := \mathcal{E} \cap T_pM$.

To show that $\exp_p : \bar{B}_{\pi R}(0) \to M $ is surjective, let $q \in M$ be an another element. As he argued above, also by the Hopf-Rinow theorem ( his book Cor. 6.15 ) there exists a geodesic segment $\gamma : [0,L] \to M$ ( up to unit speed reparametrization ( his book p.93, Exercise 6.2. ) connecting $p$ and $q$ of length $L \le \pi R$. From these, how can we find $V \in \bar{B}_{\pi R}(0)$ such that $\exp_p(V) = \gamma_V(1) = q$ ( through some reparametrization )?

And, in the final paragraph, he argues as follows :

Finally, let $\pi : \tilde{M} \to M$ denote the universal covering space of $M$, with the metric $\tilde{g} := \pi^{*}g$. Note that in this case, $\pi$ is local isometry. By the result of Problem 6-11, $\tilde{M}$ is complete. **Note that $\tilde{g}$ also has sectional curvatures bounded below by $1/R^2$**, so $\tilde{M}$ is compact by the argument above. By the theory of covering spaces.. (omitted ).

**Q.4.** Finally I want to understand the bold statement. Can we try to use next Lemma (his book p.119, Lemma 7.2.) ?

> Lemma 7.2. The Riemann curvature endomorphism and curvature tensor are local isometry invariants. More precisely, if $\varphi : (M,g) \to (\tilde{M},\tilde{g})$ is a local isometry, then $\varphi^{*}(\tilde{Rm}) = Rm$.

It seems that there is possibility that this trial works but I can't make formal proof until now.

Understanding these issues will enhance understanding theory of Riemannian Geometry. Thanks for reading. Can anyone helps?

Comment: For Q1, What if we consider $V_0\perp \gamma '$ in Th. 4.11?

Comment: For Q3, Can you figure out that what is the "**space of all points in 
$M$ that can be connected to 
$p$ by a geodesic segment of length at most $\pi R$**"? For simplicity consider 2-plane $E$.  what is the "**space of all points in 
$E$ that can be connected to 
the origin by a geodesic segment of length at most $\pi R$**?

Comment: Thanks, for Q.1. , I used " For a geodesic $\gamma : I \to M$ with $a \in I$, a jacobi field $J$ along $\gamma$ is normal if and only if $ J(a) \perp \dot{\gamma}(a)$ and $D_t J(a) \perp \dot{\gamma}(a)$." (and used some more theorems ). And for Q.3., I noticed that $\exp_p(\bar{B}_{\pi R}(0) )$ is the closed metric ball of radius $\pi R$ around $p$ ( his book, p.106 ). True? Anyway thanks. So, it remains to show the questions Q.2 and Q.4. If you have time, can you give me a hint? For Q.2, what should I catch?

Comment: For Q4, can you obtain sec curvature from $Rm$? if so, note that $\varphi^{*}(\tilde{Rm}) (x,y,z,w) = Rm(\varphi_*x,\varphi_*y,\varphi_*z,\varphi_*w)$ for $x,y,z,w\in \mathfrak{X}(M)$.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out. I check it! :) Finally, can you give me a hint for the second question? It's the last hurdle~

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Let $V_0\perp \gamma '$ in Thm. 4.11.
2. By "jump" it means the following for broken curve segment (FIGURE 6.6. in the book):
   [image]
3. To prove that $\exp$ is surjective here, we need a direction $V$ and a $t$. (Proposition 5.7. - b). Let $\gamma$ be a geodesic connection $p$ to $q$ of length $\leq \pi R$. now let $V$ to be initial velocity of this geodesic and we are sure that there is a $t$ that make this equation valid because we defined $\gamma$ be an geodesic connection $p$ to $q$.
4. It follows from local isometry property of Riemannian universal covering space (that follows from Lemma 7.2.) that $K_M(\pi_*\Pi) = K_{\widetilde{M}}(\Pi)$. So both have same sectional curvature lower bound.

Comment: Thanks. For the question 2, as noted in the Proposition 6.5, $\Delta_iD_tV :=D_tV(a_i^{+}) - D_t V(a_i^{-})$. And I'm now struggling with showing $\Sigma_{i=1}^{k-1} \langle \Delta_iD_t V, V(a_i) \rangle =0$. Perhaps, $\langle D_t V(a_i^{+}) , V(a_i) \rangle, \langle D_t V(a_i^{-}) , V(a_i) \rangle =0 $ for each $i$? What should I catch? Can we use the explicit formula for the $V(t)$ and $D_tV(t)$ as above in the question? Can we try to use the theorem 5.2. -(c), (d) in his book? What theorem can we try to use? Can you give me a more hint? :)

Comment: I am busy and your comment looks ok. But what confuse me is that, is that really needs to assume that the geodesic is broken here? I think $\gamma$ is smooth (not sure) and without jumps!

Comment: Yes, maybe. Certainly, in the first paragraph in the proof of the Theorem 11.7, if we can choose the minimizing unit speed geodesic segment $\gamma$ so that it has no broken points ( does the Hopf-Rinow theorem Cor.6.15 in his book guarantee such existence? ), then maybe(?) we don't need to consider the additional term. However, this issue seems to remain obscure. Thanks for time.

Comment: Perhaps, there is a possibility that there is no nonsmooth points of $V$. The author states in the second paragraph of the Theorem 11. 7 that "$V$ is a proper normal vector field along $\gamma : I := [0, L] \to M$ ." And by definition ( p.56 in his book ), a vector field along a curve $\gamma : I \to M$ is a 'smooth' map $V : I \to TM$ such that $V(t) \in T_{\gamma(t)}M$ for every $t \in I$. Thanks.

Comment: Maybe Professor [@jacklee](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/1421/jack-lee) can help you.

Comment: Thanks !  Is there a way to contact/ask jack lee through math-stackexchange? Perhaps such a function exists in math-stackexchange? :) Or E-mail ?

Comment: It is not polite to comment under posts of others to answer your question. I think email is better. you can find his email in his webpage http://www.math.washington.edu/~lee

Comment: If you got your answer, please add it here for me and future readers.

Comment: O.K. Yes! ~~~~~